# Is Google Cloud Datastore available in terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, terraform

I plan to use terraform to setup a Google Cloud Datastore, however I cannot find any in the documentation. Is this resource available in terraform?

Comment: Not at the moment. Same pains. Have to initialise the cloud datastore via the console. Once you have one entity, you can use code to create your objects.

Answer (score 2):

It is available with terraform now. Strangely or maybe not it is configurable through app engine resource (strangely not as it looks both apis are depended on each other).

You can find more [google_app_engine_application resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/app_engine_application)

My example configuration:

```
resource google_app_engine_application app {
  location_id   = "europe-west2"
  database_type = "CLOUD_FIRESTORE"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat. App Engine and Cloud Datastore are tied at the hip in terms of creation (creating one always creates the other with a 1:1 mapping). This means you can use use the `app-engine` block to create Cloud Datastore.

> The `app_engine` block has the following configuration options:
>
> - [location_id](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_project.html#location_id) - (Required) The location to serve the app from.

Location is also the Cloud Datastore [location](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/locations).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as an official module available here:

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/cloud-datastore/google/0.1.0

More info from the Google cloud documentation:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/magic-modules/index.html

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so.

See : https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/1253 & https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/60

Answer (score 0):

Ali was right. There is a module available. But for some reason, its not updated into official terraform documentation.

I noticed following line:

> These variables must be set in the module block when using this
>   module.